# Zoom_changed - Center

Tags: javascript

[Example for my Requirement Link :::](http://www.hostelbars.com/map_test_v3_1.html)when we click on marker it should display info window and when we zoom in using scroll,it should be zoom on marker only.when i am googling for the same i found some code to my requirement then i integrated it in my code but i did't achieve my requirement.Following is my code $WL.Maps.Event.addListener(oMarker, "click", function(e)

```
{
            if (oMarker.vehicleId !== oSelf.get($W.LiveTrack.ATTR_SELECTED_VEHICLE)) {
                oSelf.set($W.LiveTrack.ATTR_SELECTED_VEHICLE, oMarker.vehicleId);
            }
            else{
                alert('In else Block');
                oInfoWindow.drawAndMoveTo({
                    position: oMarker.getPosition(),
                    map: oGMap,
                    content: {
                    overview: oSelf._getContentOverviewTable(oVehicle),
                    details: oSelf._getContentDetailTable(oVehicle)
                }
            });
                $WL.Maps.Event.addListener(oMarker, 'zoom_changed', function() {
                    alert('In Zoom_changed Listener');
                    oGMap.setCenter(oMarker.getPosition()) });
                  });
          }
        });
    },
```

Comment: What browser did you test it with? Works on chrome

Comment: For me that works in Firefox as well. If i understand you right, your problem is, that it should always center the symbol that has been clicked when zooming. It does exactly that for me

Comment: But when i integrate this code to my code its not working can u help me to resolve if u want  i will send total code for u

Comment: I thought the link was from your page, not a real life example where it is working. Please edit your initial post, so people will see what is going wrong and are able to help. Please show the relevant parts of your code and explain where you put the Code-Snippet in to try and fix it.

Comment: how to send remaining code to u....